# Why am I getting 2 outputs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the whole script sir.
The problem is that when i release .there will be two coins that will spawn instead of one.
thank you for the help

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class coinControler : MonoBehaviour {
int flag;
int x = 0;
float xScale = 0.3f;
float zScale = 0.3f;
float xInterval = 0.01f;
float zInterval = 0.01f;
public GameObject coinobj;
public GameObject coin0;

Vector3 scale;

// Use this for initialization
void Start (){
    //for 1st coin
    scale = coinobj.transform.localScale;
    scale.z = zScale;
    scale.x = xScale;
    coinobj.transform.localScale = scale;
    //for 2nd coin
    scale = coin1.transform.localScale;
    scale.z = zScale;
    scale.x = xScale;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    touchInput();
}


void touchInput() {
//interval of the coin growth
    if(x%20 == 0 && x >= 20)
    {
        xInterval += 0.01f;
        zInterval += 0.01f;
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            //Change Scale  
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                scale.x += xInterval;
                scale.z += zInterval;
                coinobj.transform.localScale = scale;
                Debug.Log("......" + x + "........");
                x++;
            }
        }
    //the coin will drop after the user releases touch
        else 
    {

            //drop the coin
            coinobj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                coinSpawn0();
                Debug.Log("Drop Coin");
            } 
        }
    }
}
//Spawn function of the second coin
public void coinSpawn0()
{
    Vector3 coinPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    Instantiate(coin0, coinPos, Quaternion.identity);
    scale = coin0.transform.localScale;
    scale.z = zScale;
    scale.x = xScale;
    coin0.transform.localScale = scale;
    xInterval = 0.01f;
    zInterval = 0.01f;
    flag = 1;
}
}
```

Output:

......42........
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

......42........
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

......43........
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

......43........
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Show Flag:1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Show Flag:1
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

[image]

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: as you can see . im getting 2 outputs . it should be 42 43 and flag 1 only . im sorry im new to this

Comment: put the whole script.

Comment: hi sir . i editted my post . i already put the whole script

Answer (score 0):

If you write out the TouchPhase you should know more.

I suppose, at the beginning of a touch, that touch will go through two phases at the same position:

1. Begin (at x=42)
2. Stationary, as you are not moving (still x=42)

It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve, though.

Comment: Hi sir . What im trying to do is . When you touch and hold my coin gets bigger . And then after that when you release , the coin will drop and the second coin will spawn . The problem is that . There are 2 outputs . So there are two coins spawning at the same time . Im sorry but its my first time using unity and c# . Can you explain it to me why im having 2 outputs . Thank you sir .